# how to use a CImg image in SDL

Tags: sdl, cimg

I'm trying to display an image generated with CImg on a SDL surface.

CImg saves the image data as a simple array (e.g. red values before green values, before blue values).

I've read that using RWops is the way to go, but somehow I cannot figure out how to convert the image data to an RWops structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used `CImg`, but basically, what you need to do is create a way to transform your `CImg` data to follow a known image format, for example, `bitmap`.

Unfortunately, `CImg` doesn't seem to provide this kind of feature, as seen on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/cimg/discussion/334630/thread/f6d5c7fc), but somebody was kind enough to provide the code in the thread (although there seems to be formatting issues).

Using the code in the thread above and [SDL_LoadBMP_RW](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/SDL_LoadBMP_RW), you'd do something like:

```
unsigned char *bitmapImage = NULL; //the target-buffer
bitmapImage = cimg_image.save_bmp2buffer(); //get the bmp-buffer

// the buffer size is based on the bmp format, according to save_bmp2buffer it should be something like:
// I simplified a bit his formula, some operations didn't seem necessary
// The 54 represents the size of a bitmap header, the rest is the padded pixel content size
int imgSize = 54 + (3 * cimg_image.width() + 4 - (3 * cimg_image.width()) % 4) * cimg_image.height();

SDL_RWops* rw = SDL_RWFromMem(bitmapImage, imgSize );

SDL_Surface* yourSurface = SDL_LoadBMP_RW(rw, 1); // 1 will free the rw when done

free(bitmapImage);
```

This code is not tested, but should be a good starting point!